# How to Ensure $lookup Maps to Correctly Corresponding Object in MongoDB View

Tags: arrays, mongodb, view, lookup, studio3t

In my MongoDB/Node backend, I am creating a view using Studio 3T to return some subset of data from a collection. I am also doing a `$lookup` to bring in some data from a second collection, and injecting that in where a mongoID would normally appear as a reference to the other collection.

I am then using `$project` to shape how that data displays.

This is what my initial `$project` looks like, and this is stage 1 of my pipeline:

```
{ "name" : 1.0, "dob" : 1.0, "coverage" : 1.0, "payer" : 1.0 }
```

For stage 2, I'm doing my `$lookup`, which looks like this:

```
{ "from" : "payers", "localField" : "coverage.payer", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "payerInfo" }
```

Finally I'm shaping how the data looks with a step like this:

```
"coverage" : { "payer" : { "id" : "$payerInfo._id", "name" : "$payerInfo.name" }
```

The problem I'm running into is that, if for instance, "coverage" -- which is from the primary collection - has more than one object in the array, then the same "payer" info -- which is from the secondary collection -- is being dropped in for *each* of those. So basically the indexing is off. There should be a different payerId and payerName for each object in the coverage array.

What operation can I run to ensure that the correctly corresponding payer info (pulled from the second collection via the $lookup), gets dropped into the appropriate object within the "coverage" array?

Below is what the outputted data looks like (and, as I say, this is incorrect. Right now the same payer info is being added to both objects in the "coverage" array, when those should be different).

```
    "coverage": [
        {
            "payer": {
                "id": [
                    "12345"
                ],
                "name": [
                    {
                        "long": "National United",
                        "short": "NU"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "field2": value,
            "field3": value,
            "field4": value,
        },
        {
            "payer": {
                "id": [
                    "12345"
                ],
                "name": [
                    {
                        "long": "National United",
                        "short": "NU"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "field2": value,
            "field3": value,
            "field4": value,

        }
    ]
```

What additional operation can I add to the view pipeline to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$unwind` before the `$lookup` and add an `$unwind` and `$addFields` with to inlcude the fields of your choice from joined collection document and another `$addFields` to move the matching payer info into coverage and `$group` stage after `$project` to pull all the coverages into array in 3.4 version.

Something like

Stage 2

```
{"$unwind":"$coverage"}
```

Stage 3

```
{ "from" : "payers", "localField" : "coverage.payer", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "payerInfo" }
```

Stage 4

```
 {"$unwind":"$payerInfo"}
```

Stage 5

```
{"$addFields":{ "payerInfo" : { "id" : "$payerInfo._id", "name" : "$payerInfo.name" }
```

Stage 6

```
{"$addFields":{"coverage.payer":"$payerInfo"}}
```

Stage 7

```
{"$project":{"payerInfo":0}}
```

Stage 8

```
{"$group":{"_id":"$_id", "coverage":{"$push":"$coverage"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, so much @Veeram, I will give this a shot.

Comment: For the most part this works. The only issue is, the other fields from the primary collection that I pulled in with a "$project" in stage 1 are no longer showing up in the outputted data. Any idea why?

Comment: Np. Yes you have to include them in $group stage. Something like `{"$group":{"_id":"$_id", "name" : {$first:"$name"}, list other fields, "coverage":{"$push":"$coverage"}}}`